# AJAX load triggered on window scroll, but how to stop it loading the same thing repeatedly

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll

I have a simple AJAX function which loads more search results as the user scrolls down a page.

```
$(window).scroll(function () { // fire the load stuff function as scroller gets near the bottom of the page
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= parseInt($(document).height() - $(window).height() - 150)) {
       var finished = 1;
       if (finished == 1) {
          finished = 0;
          loadMore(function () { finished = 1; });
       };
    };
});
```

This works, except it's firing the `loadMore` function every time the window is scrolled, obviously.

So, checking the Firebug console, it's loading loads of times.

What it needs to do is not run another instance of `loadMore` until the last instance has finished.

I have tried putting in a callback and a variable (the `finished` variable you see in the code) but this doesn't work.

How can I ensure the user can scroll, but the function is only trigger when there is no other instance of this function processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work, you need to set the finished outside the scroll event, because it is executed each time the user scrolls

```
var finished = 1;
        $(window).scroll(function () { // fire the load stuff function as scroller gets near the bottom of the page
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= parseInt($(document).height() - $(window).height() - 150)) {           
           if (finished == 1) {
              finished = 0;
              loadMore(function () { finished = 1; });
           };
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring your `finished` variable **inside** the function and setting its value to 1, so your `if` statement will always evaluate to true.

Make `finished` global rather than local, initialised to 1, then use the same code.

Answer (score 0):

declare `finished` inside the body onload function ,
 and after that your scroll functions can start.

```
$(function(){
   finished=1;

   $(window).scroll(function () { 
// fire the load stuff function as scroller gets near the bottom of the page   
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= parseInt($(document).height() - $(window).height() - 150)) 
    {         
       if (finished == 1) {           
           finished = 0;           
           loadMore(function () 
           { 
              finished = 1; 
           });        
       };     
    }; 
 }); 
 });
```